# react-navigation swipe to go back doesn't trigger

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am using stack navigation and I want to use swipe to go back. However, even when I swipe the screen all the way to the right the app doesn't navigate to the previous screen and the screen slides back.

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Main from './components/Main'
import Options from './components/Options'
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <View>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" screenOptions={{ gestureResponseDistance: {horizontal: 20}}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={Main} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="OptionsScreen" component={Options} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

To be clear I am able to swipe the screen but once I let go of my finger the screen slides back to its initial position and I am not able trigger swipe to go back no matter how fast I swipe.

Comment: Why you wrapped your stack navigator with view ? Is there any special requirement, because wrapping stack navigator with view can be create issue. If there is no special requirement to wrap your stack navigator with view then remove <View> and try again.

Comment: Removing <View> didn't fix the issue. It still has the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and updating @react-navigation/stack to the latest version fixed it.

my prev package.json with the issue

```
{...
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": ""~2.5.0",
...}
```

after

```
{...
   "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.4",
...}
```

So I removed `react-native-gesture-handler` from dependencies, because `react-navigation/stack` already has it in it's own. And after that i have `react-native-gesture-handler@2.8.0` in my package-lock and it works without the issue.

You can check what dependencies of `react-native-gesture-handler` you have in your project using:

```
npm why react-native-gesture-handler
```

and you should get something like this:

```
react-native-gesture-handler@2.8.0 peer
node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler
  peer react-native-gesture-handler@">= 1.0.0" from @react-navigation/stack@6.3.4
  node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
    @react-navigation/stack@"^6.3.4" from the root project
```

If you want to use specific version of `react-native-gesture-handler` you can always override it in package.json like this:

```
{ 
...
  "dependencies": {...},
  "overrides": {
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.8.0"
  }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try gestureEnabled : false.

```
<Stack.Screen name={stringAssets.BottomTabs} component={BottomTabs} options={{ headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

try `gestureEnabled: true` in option of stack because this props enable back swipe

```
export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <View>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Main" screenOptions={{ gestureResponseDistance: {horizontal: 20}}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={Main} options={{ headerShown: false,gestureEnabled: true }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="OptionsScreen" component={Options} options={{ headerShown: false,gestureEnabled: true }}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </View>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: According to documentation, the default value for gestureEnabled is true. Setting it explicitly didn't fix the problem.

Comment: is it possible to call a function on swiping back?

Answer (score 0):

After experiencing the same problem, I found out that the problem was a useEffect that was being triggered over and over.

```
UseEffect(() => { *code here* })
```

changed to:

```
UseEffect(() => { *code here* }, [])
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error

Answer (score 0):

Try **detachPreviousScreen: false** in options of Stack Screen with **gestureEnabled: true** for ios if screen freezes on swipe back.